# Can you add a normal SSL certificate to the base of a wildcard certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a wildcard SSL certificate setup on *.domain.com and its working fine. I now want to add a single ssl certificate to domain.com.

Is this likely to cause me problems? I assume not, but I thought it would be good to check that someone else has done it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a different IP for each different SSL cert you use. So you'll need two IPs.

It's not clear why you want to use another SSL cert, is it an EV cert?

Comment: Speaking for Windows IIS 6 and beyond, there is a feature called SSL Host Headers that allows for this very scenario.  (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/596b9108-b1a7-494d-885d-f8941b07554c.mspx)

Comment: Dscouduc: SSL Host Headers is a misnomer at best; it allows you to use **one** cert for **multiple** sites (the poster asked about **multiple** certs for **one** site); but the cert has to be a wildcard cert that matches all the sites covered.

Comment: Not sure why you think it's a misnomer... many people choose to do this for their environment to avoid having to use multiple IP addresses for their websites.

Comment: It's a misnomer because it's stetting up the SSL tunnel without any knowledge of the Host Header; after the tunnel is successfully setup, it uses standard Host Headers to determine the site.

Comment: Perhaps.  But what is happening is most important.  The SSL connection can take place without SSL warnings and the IIS Server can redirect the client to the appropriate web site based on the "host headers"...  Sounds pretty clear and simple to me.  If you want to get hung up on the title that's fine, but you can't argue with the result...  Cheers.

Comment: Misnomer or not, you seem to have missed the point of the comment, that it allows multiple sites to use one certificate; which is not what the original question was asking (how to use multiple certificates on one site).

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem mixing the wildcard and specific certificates.  Not sure why you would need to do this as the wildcard certificate should be able to handle all domain.com requests.  You should also be able to bind the same wildcard certificate to multiple websites, meaning you don't need a unique certificate for each website.

Comment: For future reference: a wildcard certificate for *.example.com is not by itself valid for example.com, but most (all?) wildcard certs also include example.com as a Subject Alternative Name.

Answer (score -1):

If you have wildcard ssl certificate so why you want to purchase other ssl certificate.

Wildcard SSL certificate is the best solution for your requirement. It can secure your main domain (domain.com) and unlimited sub domains (*.domain.com). it means your main domain and all sub domains are secures with single wildcard certificate.

Comment: No. If you have a wildcard `*.example.com`, the wildcard is only valid for all sub-domains under `example.com`, not for `example.com` itself.